# Best method for generating html content to a single web page

Tags: php

Good day everyone!

I have a single page, this page has no dynamic content.

I have a set of links. What I need is to have content placed on the page based on the link the user clicks.

Example: I have pictures of animals. When the user click a Zebra, the Zebra info is placed on the page.

So the page does not change, meaning the content on the page changes but not the page it self.

The idea is instead of creating different html pages for each animal profile, the profile is generated to the page from another source.

Is is this possible?

What will be the best way to get this accomplish?

Thanks everyone!

IC

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use jquery to do this. Set your data in hidden divs and just move them into the "display" area when the appropriate image is clicked on.

Comment: This, except change "jquery" to "javascript". He can use any library he wants, or no library at all.